# An adjective for two things that have bearing on each other?

Tags: single-word-requests

> 1. A has a bearing on B.
> 2. B has a bearing on A.

Now I want to say the above 2 sentences in the following single sentence:

> A and B are ------ .

I thought about words such as "interrelated" or "interconnected", but they are basically about "relation" or "connection", while "bearing" has a nuance of "affecting" or "influencing".

Comment: Why exactly does *bearing* mean in your example?

Comment: @michael.hor257k a relation of affecting or having an influence.

Comment: You are providing a dictionary definition. I asked about your specific use. Currently your question is too abstract to answer comfortably.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I find it clear enough and complete.

Comment: @Kris Good for you. Why should I care?

Comment: @michael.hor257k You should because the question is still valid and does not merit a close vote.

Comment: @Kris Yes, I understand that is your opinion. What I don't understand is why you need to shove it down my throat.

Comment: Easy, @michael.hor257k No offence. You still can retract any close vote you may have done.

Comment: @Kris Actually I can't, because I haven't. Now I will.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

One such word implying "both having an influence on each other" is ***correlated***.

> A and B are ***correlated*** .

Collins:

> **[correlate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/correlate)**
>
> *past participle* **correlated**
>
> **1**. [verb]   If one thing correlates with another, there is a close similarity or connection between them, often because one thing causes
>   the other. You can also say that two things correlate.
>
> At the highest executive levels, earnings and performance aren't
>   always correlated.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
>   Publishers

ODO:

> **[correlate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/correlate)**
>   VERB   [NO OBJECT]
>   **1** Have a mutual relationship or connection, in which one thing affects or depends on another.
>
> ‘the study found that success in the educational system correlates
>   highly with class’

Answer (score 0):

*meta:* Off the top of my head (and looking at it from the other perspective), for the time being:

***interdependent*** (ODOL)

> ‘In addition, there are some interdependent relationships between flower and pollinator sizes.’
>   (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interdependent)

That is, each influences the other; each is a factor for the other.

Note that *dependence* need not mean one cannot exist without the other but that one is **influenced/ affected** by the other.